# Destructor of a Trie Node in a Trie Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I'm creating an implementation of a Trie with a TrieNode struct which is an individual node and a TrieSet class which is the complete tree. Here is the signature of my TrieNode:

```
struct TrieNode {
    TrieNode(bool in, TrieNode *p);
    ~TrieNode();
    void deleteChildren(TrieNode *node);
    bool isLeafNode();

    bool inSet;
    TrieNode *parent;
    TrieNode *children[30];
};
```

I'm trying to define the destructor which first recursively deletes all the children and then finally deletes the node, but I'm getting a segmentation fault. Here is the code for my constructor, destructor and its helper function:

```
TrieNode::TrieNode(bool in, TrieNode *p)
{
    inSet = in;
    parent = p;
}

TrieNode::~TrieNode()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        if(children[i] != nullptr)
        {
            delete children[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to follow either the Rule of Three, Rule of Five, or Rule of Zero.

Comment: Can you add the code for your constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `children` array is uninitialized, so the data will be random garbage and trying to delete them Undefined Behavior, and likely a crash.

Calling `delete node` in `deleteChildren` is wrong, as it results in a recursive destructor call (just like calling `delete this` from within the destructor).

There may be other issues.  I haven't looked extensively.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed up the code a bit to get rid of the recursive calls. Sadly, I'm still getting a seg fault.